# PHP SQL - Multiple select from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `SELECT` query from one table that works great as follows:

```
 $sql = "SELECT count(max720) AS anzahlpositive1 from table where (((max720 - lastsignal)/lastsignal)*100) >= 1 AND (((max720 - lastsignal)/lastsignal)*100) < 2 AND max720 != ''";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

But I had 20-30 of them with other values.
For every `SELECT` query a new connection established.. I think thats a lot of perfomance.

Thats the 2nd:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(max720) AS anzahlpositive2 from table where (((max720 - lastsignal)/lastsignal)*100) >= 2 AND (((max720 - lastsignal)/lastsignal)*100) < 3 AND max720 != ''";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Is is possible to do this in ONE select? (better performance)

I have tried with `UNION` (but i think its for 2 or more tables)

Is that a solution?

```
$sql = "SELECT 1";
$sql .= "SELECT 2";
$sql .= "SELECT 3";
...

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $anzahlpositive1 ;
echo $anzahlpositive2 ;
echo $anzahlpositive3 ;
....
}
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What do you mean by "For every `SELECT` query a new connection established"? Just use the same connection and perform multiple queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  count(max720) AS ...
union all
select  count(max720) AS ...
```

You can use as many unions as you want, read the difference between `union` and `union all`, `union` will discard duplicates.

Comment: ok.. now i use it with UNION ALL! but when i try to make an output (while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row[first], echo [$row[second],... } ... only the first is shown. the second is "Undefined index" !?

Comment: name all of them as total and print as $row['total']

Comment: works. different, but works. and how can i give a specific result? like.. only the 2nd? like that ... print $row['total'][1]  (but doesnt work)

Comment: why will you need that? you can put in array the value in another array and use the index to access it.